# show blank page after call javascript from java

Tags: java, javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I made an application with ionic framework. i want to update my html progress bar using javascript function called from native java while my java run on asynctask. 
First, this is my angular controller :

```
.controller('DMCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.updateProgress = function(name,progress){
        loader.setProgress(progress); //loader is my progress bar in view
    };
});
```

And this is my java to call updateProgress :

```
private void updateProgress(final String name, final int progress, final int max){
    mGap.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            double data = (double)progress/(double)max;
            mGap.loadUrl("javascript: updateProgress('"+name+"',"+"'"+data+"');"); //mGap is my cordova activity
        }

    });
}
```

i call that method inside an asynctask and worked successfully. But logcat shows error that my javascript function updateProgress is undefined and my app goes black screen. it looks like it call blank page instead of calling my javascript function. And here the log :

```
04-01 14:43:20.197: I/DataAdapter(12328): Start getPXPreservedList(52025900) >> Wed Apr 01 14:43:20 GMT+07:00 2015
04-01 14:43:20.198: E/dalvikvm(12328): [DVM] mmap return base = 48159000
04-01 14:43:20.211: D/dalvikvm(12328): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 398K, 60% free 3101K/7687K, external 0K/2560K, paused 14ms
04-01 14:43:20.215: I/System.out(12328): [socket][2] connection 192.168.1.57/192.168.1.57:8080;LocalPort=47448(20000)
04-01 14:43:20.215: I/System.out(12328): 192.168.1.57/192.168.1.57:8080(20000)
04-01 14:43:20.215: I/OSNetworkSystem(12328): OSNetworkSystem_connect fd=-1; timeout = 20000
04-01 14:43:20.217: I/System.out(12328): Socket[addr=/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=47448]
04-01 14:43:20.217: I/System.out(12328): [socket][/192.168.1.50:47448]
04-01 14:43:20.283: I/System.out(12328): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:47448]
04-01 14:43:20.338: D/CordovaWebView(12328): >>> loadUrl(javascript: updateProgress('pxconfig','0.13636363636363635');)
04-01 14:43:20.338: D/PluginManager(12328): init()
04-01 14:43:20.344: I/webkit/webview(12328): Webview.loadUrl() this=org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView@40534fc0url: javascript: updateProgress('pxconfig','0.13636363636363635');
04-01 14:43:20.347: D/CordovaLog(12328): : Line 1 : Uncaught ReferenceError: updateProgress is not defined
04-01 14:43:20.347: E/Web Console(12328): Uncaught ReferenceError: updateProgress is not defined at :1
```

Comment: Your updateProgress function is available only in DMCtrl scope. You're trying to call global function updateProgress which is undefined. 
To keep business logic clean, maybe it will be better to inverse that call? I mean call from Ionic and then update progress, instead updating your app from external.

Comment: @Łukasz how can i make my function global?

Comment: @Łukasz or can you suggest me what is the best method to update my progress to html view?

Comment: My suggestion is to emit an event and implement the action on that event in Ionic

Comment: @Łukasz i dont know how to create event in ionic. for now, i just periodically call my native java to get current progress. can you give me example how to make event in ionic?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hxtpoe/uvs103gy/ it should be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to emit an event and implement the action on that event in Ionic. It should be helpful [jsfiddle.net/hxtpoe/uvs103gy](http://jsfiddle.net/hxtpoe/uvs103gy)

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['App']);
});

angular.module('App', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$document', '$scope', function($document, $scope) {
      $scope.user = {'name' : "Hello"};
      $document.on('myevent', function() {
          $scope.$apply(
              function() {
                     $scope.user.name = "hello my event!";
              });

      })
  }]);

// end of angular/ionic app

var button = document.getElementById("emit");

button.onclick = function() {
    var event = new CustomEvent("myevent", {});
    document.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```